# linux env command does not work as expected?

Tags: linux, env

These 2 lines work as expected:

```
$ env NEW=hello bash -c "env | grep hello"
NEW=hello
$ env NEW=hello bash -c "echo $PATH"
/bin:/usr/bin
```

But I don't know why the following does not work (as expected).

```
$ env NEW=hello bash -c "echo $NEW"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ env NEW=hello bash -c "echo $NEW"
```

You're using double-quotes on the argument to bash here, so the `$NEW` in the argument is expanded by your current shell, *not* by the `bash` command you're executing. Since `$NEW` isn't set in your current shell, the command is expanded to `bash -c "echo "`.

Use single-quotes on the argument to solve this:

```
$ env NEW=hello bash -c 'echo $NEW'
hello
```